# Implementing NSTimer in MVVM architecture

Tags: swift, mvvm, nstimer

I want to implement a NSTimer to show a chronometer using a NSTimeInterval, so I looked around and found this code, which I put into my ViewModel layer:

```
public class ViewModel {

public func startTimer() {
    //if !timer.valid {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
    //}
}

@objc public func updateTime() -> String {
    let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    //Find the difference between current time and start time.

    var elapsedTime: NSTimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

    //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.

    let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)

    elapsedTime -= (NSTimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

    //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.

    let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)

    elapsedTime -= NSTimeInterval(seconds)

    //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

    let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
    let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)

    //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel

    return "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds)"
}
}
```

And I want to show the current elapsed time on my view, so tried this but it didn't work:

```
viewModel?.startTimer()
timerLabel.text = viewModel?.updateTime()
```

How can I show the latest result of `updateTime()` on my ViewController label?

Comment: FWIW, there's no need to run a timer every 0.01 seconds, as the screen refresh is capped as 60fps. I'd probably suggest a `CADisplayLink` rather than `NSTimer`. Also, rather than calculating the elapsed time yourself and building the string like this, you might want to use a `NSDateComponentsFormatter` with a `formatter.allowedUnits = [.Minute, .Second]`, `formatter.unitsStyle = .Positional`, and `formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = .Pad`. Then, to update label in timer/display link handler, it's just `timerLabel.text = formatter.stringFromDate(startDate, toDate: NSDate())`.

Answer (score 0):

The `updateTime` method cannot just return the string. It has to initiate the updating of the label in question. You can either code it to update the label directly, or you can provide a closure that `updateTime` will call when it has the string value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement Rob's answer, but couldn't really get the grasp of CAdisplayLink in a MVVM architecture and came up with the same problem of updating a GUI element periodically in a different view.
However I used my RAC knowledge and created and passed a `RACSignal` to update my ViewController:

```
RACSignal.interval(1.0, onScheduler: .mainThreadScheduler()).subscribeNext({ _ in
                self.timerLabel.text = self.viewModel?.updateTime()
            })
```